# Swap two elements in static array using STL

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

Assume I have an array, `int array[3] = {1,2,3};` and I want to swap the first and last element so that I have `array = {3,2,1};` How can I do this using the STL ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use either `std::swap` or `std::iter_swap`.

```
    std::swap(array[0], array[2]);
    std::iter_swap(array, array+2);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that doesn't rely on the length of the array being 3, you can use `std::begin` and `std::end` to find the beginning and end of the `array`, then `std::iter_swap` them

```
std::iter_swap(std::begin(array), std::end(array)-1);
```

*Note*: the `-1` because the `end` of an iterable refers to one element past the end.  You'll need to `#include <iterator>` and `#include <algorithm>` for this to work.

If you want to be more flexible you can create a templated function

```
template <typename T>
void swap_first_and_last(T& seq) {
    std::iter_swap(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq)-1);
}
```

which can then be called with static arrays (or other containers)

```
    swap_first_and_last(array);
```

*Another note*: with an initializer list, you don't need to provide a size for the array.  The compiler will figure one out based on the number of elements you provide:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3};  //empty []
```